# Using the looker embedsdk the connect() promise never resolves using an sso url

Tags: embed, looker

Using the looker embedsdk the connect() promise never resolves using an sso url.

Using the debugger in my dev environment I can see at this point in the @looker/chatty code there is a switch against `evt.data.action` which is always undefined. The debug in the line above fires many times but I just see:

`looker:chatty:host window received +0ms undefined undefined`

In the debugger I can see `evt.data` = `{"type":"page:changed","page":{"type":"dashboard","absoluteUrl":"https://company.looker.com:19999/embed/dashboards/104?embed_domain=http://localhost:3100","url":"/embed/dashboards/104?embed_domain=http://localhost:3100"}}`

So `evt.data.data` and `evt.data.action` are both undefined.

The iframe loads the dashboard fine. I’ve added localhost:3100 to the embed allow list and I’m including `?embed_domain=http://localhost:3100&sdk=2` in the target url when creating the sso url.

This is my code:

```
  const [embed, setEmbed] = useState<LookerEmbedDashboard>();
  const embedUrl = useLookerSSOEmbed(dashboard);

  const embedCtrRef = useCallback(
    (el) => {
      if (el && embedUrl) {
        el.innerHTML = '';
        LookerEmbedSDK.init('https://company.looker.com:19999');
        LookerEmbedSDK.createDashboardWithUrl(embedUrl)
          .appendTo(el)
          .build()
          .connect()
          .then((dashboard) => {
            setEmbed(dashboard);
            console.log('dashboard', dashboard);
          })
          .catch((error) => console.log('error', error));
      }
    },
    [embedUrl]
  );

  return <EmbedContainer ref={embedCtrRef}></EmbedContainer>;
};
```

This is the part of the code in @looker/chatty host.js That it dies in. The single case in the switch never hits since `evt.data.action` is always undefinded:

```
var windowListener = function (evt) {
if (!_this.isValidMsg(evt)) {
    // don't reject here, since that breaks the promise resolution chain
    ChattyHost._debug('window received invalid', evt);
    return;
}
ChattyHost._debug('window received', evt.data.action, evt.data.data);
switch (evt.data.action) {
    case client_messages_1.ChattyClientMessages.Syn:
        if (_this._port) {
            // If targetOrigin is set and we receive another Syn, the frame has potentially
            // navigated to another valid webpage and we should re-connect
            if ((_this._targetOrigin && _this._targetOrigin === '*') ||
                _this._targetOrigin === evt.origin) {
                ChattyHost._debug('reconnecting to', evt.origin);
                _this._port.close();
            }
            else {
                ChattyHost._debug('rejected new connection from', evt.origin);
                return;
            }
        }
        _this._port = evt.ports[0];
        _this._port.onmessage = eventListener;
        _this.sendMsg(host_messages_1.ChattyHostMessages.SynAck);
        _this._state = ChattyHostStates.SynAck;
        break;
}
```

};

Comment: Did you solve your issue?